# Are all Nexus 5 phones sold unlocked?

Tags: nexus-5

Are all Nexus 5 phones sold unlocked (i.e., not tied to a specific carrier)? If I buy a Nexus 5 from a store in Germany will I be able to use it in another country (Brazil)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, at this point. But, there's a talk about Sprint-locked Nexus 5.

**Note:** If you intend to use 4G LTE, then you need to check LTE market-compatibility, too. Other than that, you're good to use the phone in both countries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, currently. However this could change, the US carriers sometimes sell locked phones.

There is currently only one Nexus 5 variant, so you don't have to worry about LTE compatibility issues.